# Google Maps, initialize and fetch map when clicking button and not on page load

Tags: javascript, google-maps, canvas, initialization

I have create two fiddles:

The first one (https://jsfiddle.net/az5tk8ns/5/) works perfectly and initializes on page load with the follwoing syntax:
`google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);`

the second fiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/az5tk8ns/8/) is exactly the same code except that the google canvas and related HTML is contained inside a DIV that is hidden by default. I click the button to un-hide the div and initialize the map. `initialize();`

The problem is that the maps part from the API is working great as I can see the source, destination and distance that the API has calculated, I am just unable to see the map.

what do I have to do with the initialize call to ensure that the google mpa is displayed correctly.

the entire initialize syntax is:

```
function initialize() {
  directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
  var chicago = new google.maps.LatLng(-28.5710903,26.0826083);
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 7,
    center: chicago
  };
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
  directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
  calcRoute();
}
```

thanks for the help as always

Comment: Just an information. Fiddle provides 4 Sections. 1 for HTML, 1 for CSS; 1 for JS and 1 for the Result. You are using 1 for all, which decreases the readability!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is not the code, it is the CSS:

```
html, body, #map-canvas {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

The `<div id="testdiv">` doesn't have a size.  Changing it to this works for me:

```
html,body, #map-canvas, #testdiv {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

[proof of concept fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/az5tk8ns/9/)

**code snippet:**

```js
var directionsDisplay;
var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
var map;

function initialize() {
  directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
  var chicago = new google.maps.LatLng(-28.5710903, 26.0826083);
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 7,
    center: chicago
  };
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
  directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
  calcRoute();
}
var origin = "pietermaritzburg, south africa",
  destinations = ["", "durban, south africa", "amanzimtoti, south africa", "ixopo, south africa"]


service = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService();

function calcRoute() {
  var waypts = [];
  for (var i = 1; i < destinations.length - 1; i++) {
    waypts.push({
      location: destinations[i],
      stopover: true
    });
  }
  var request = {
    origin: origin,
    destination: destinations[destinations.length - 1],
    waypoints: waypts,
    optimizeWaypoints: true,
    travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
  };
  directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
      directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
      var orig = document.getElementById("orig"),
        dest = document.getElementById("dest"),
        dist = document.getElementById("dist");

      orig.value = response.routes[0].legs[0].start_address;
      dest.value = response.routes[0].legs[0].end_address;
      var total_distance = 0.0;
      for (var i = 0; i < response.routes[0].legs.length; i++) {
        total_distance += response.routes[0].legs[i].distance.value;
      }
      dist.value = total_distance + " meters";
    }
  });
}

function testmap() {
  $('#testdiv').show();
  initialize();
}
```

```css
html,
body,
#map-canvas,
#testdiv {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
#panel {
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -180px;
  z-index: 5;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #999;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div style='display:none' id="testdiv">

  <div id="map-canvas"></div>
  <div id="mileage-details">Origin:
    <input id="orig" type="text" style="width:35em">
    <br>
    <br>Destination:
    <input id="dest" type="text" style="width:35em">
    <br>
    <br>Distance:
    <input id="dist" type="text" style="width:35em">
  </div>
</div>
<input type="button" onclick='testmap()' value="getmap">
```

Comment: Thank you so much - pretty dumb of me, Thanks.